# Android switch between activity without data loss

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've three activity kind A1 > A2 > A3 where A1 is a login form, A2 are collections of a buttons which start A3 and A3 interacts with the logged user but if there's no users activity, a timer start again A1 for login. What I want is return to A3 (bypassing A2) without loss data of A3. I don't want putExtra in Intent because the variables are too many.

Comment: I'm not really understand what you are trying to achieve, but it seems like the best solution is Shared Preference.

Answer (score 3):

try making model class and implement parcelable for it. now you can send the object of this model class as extra and retrieve it in another activity.

If you don't understand this concept, please let me know. 
Excellent page to convert any Model class to parcelable one.
Check here [Convert Model Class to Pacelable](http://www.parcelabler.com/)